# Parent/Child Hierarchy in Rust

Tags: rust

I'm trying to model a **parent/child datastructure** in Rust.
I've simplified my problem to this basic reproducer.

```rust
struct Node {
    pub name: String,
    children: Vec<Node>,
    parent: *const Node,
}

impl Node {
    pub fn new(name: &str) -> Node {
        Node {
            name: name.to_string(),
            children: vec![],
            parent: std::ptr::null()
        }
    }
    fn add_child(&mut self, mut child: Node) {
        child.parent = self;
        self.children.push(child);
    }
    fn get_child(&self, pos: usize) -> &Node {
        &self.children[pos]
    }
    fn get_parent(&self) -> &Node {
        unsafe { self.parent.as_ref().unwrap() }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut n1 = Node::new("n1");
    let mut n2 = Node::new("n2");
    let n3 = Node::new("n3");
    n2.add_child(n3);
    n1.add_child(n2);
    println!("n1: {}", n1.name);
    println!("n2: {}", n1.get_child(0).name);
    println!("n3: {}", n1.get_child(0).get_child(0).name);
    println!("n2: {}", n1.get_child(0).get_child(0).get_parent().name);
    println!("n1: {}", n1.get_child(0).get_child(0).get_parent().get_parent().name); // the second get_parent() is null ... WHY?!
}
```

For some reason, the second `get_parent()` call always returns `null` even though I clearly set it before.
I'm sure, I have a basic understanding problem here but I cannot figure it out.

Here's also a [Rust Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=de1e62189293f3567d77d955a86ced54) to the code.

**Note:** I tried using `&Node` for the parent before together with lifetime parameters but to no avail.
I'm specifically interested in why **this approach** does not work. If you have an alternative suggestions, I appreciate it, but this is not what I'm looking for here.

Comment: Not exactly sure why it fails, but your code contains UB (hint the playground let's you run miri to detect this) so you can't really expect anything from it.

Comment: Moving `Node` into `add_child` invalidates all pointers to it!

Comment: That can't be entirely true, because it works for the first parent pointer. Also, is this documented somewhere? I could not find anything related to that.

Comment: Uhm yea, only pointers to `n2` are invalidated after you assigned them.

Comment: @WolfgangZiegler Imagine if I did `let n1_boxed = Box::new(n1)` after all your `add_child` calls. There's a reason why trees in rust either use reference counting with weak parent references or id-based representations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first `add_child`

```rust
    n2.add_child(n3);
```

is fine, you haven't taken any pointers to `n3` after all, but in the second one

```rust
    n1.add_child(n2);
```

you move `n2` from it's previous position, and only in `add_child` you set `child.parent` to something else, but it's at a different location from the original `n2` which `n3.parent` still points to.

So no, you never set `n2.parent`, you only set `n1.child(0).parent`.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. Thanks a lot!
I'm still thinking too much in terms of heap objects and references.